# fabric python install problem

Tags: python, django, fabric

Just installed fabric, trying to use to same fabfile that works on a different server, getting this error here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.6/fabric.py", line 1211, in main
    load(fabfile, fail='warn')
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.6/fabric.py", line 467, in load
    execfile(filename)
  File "fabfile.py", line 2, in <module>
    from fabric.api import *
ImportError: No module named api
```

Comment: Are you sure your newly installed fabric is on PYTHONPATH? Try to run python interpreter instead of fab and `>>> from fabric import api`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you named a file fabric.py somewhere in your python path. (probably in your current working directory)
Rename it to something else and then it will not have any issues.
I accidentally do this all the time and it is annoying.

Comment: or add `from __future__ import absolute_import` to the top of your page

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have different versions of Fabric on those servers, they changed the module structure recently.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this message on my Ubuntu 9.10 machine; Ubuntu ships with an old version of fabric (0.1.1). The latest release version is 0.9.0.

```
sudo easy_install fabric
```

should get you the latest released version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I installed fabric using disutils on OS X. So I removed it and reinstalled with pip. works fine.

To remove: Delete the Fabric egg in site-packages directory.

then install using pip

```
sudo pip install fabric
```